# mongoDB TLS transport encryption check

Tags: mongodb, ssl, tls1.2

Is there any easy option beside tcpdump to find out if application to mongoDB connection is encrypted(TLS/SSL) without having access to the server mongodb.conf configuration files?
Maybe some connection configuration value that can be checked from inside the instance ?

Thanks

Comment: You can read the config file with `db.serverCmdLineOpts()` command.

Comment: Maybe I didnt clarify , but I need a way to see if current connection has the encryption active , since for example setting can be preferedTLS , but it allow non-encrypted connections as well...

Comment: I don't think so, because TLS is done on TCP level, i.e. the MongoDB instance does not even know whether connection is encrypted or not.

Comment: Hmm , this is interesting , in case those settings are provided in the mongod.conf I was expecting the mongod/mongos to be aware ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the current answer to this question is "no".

This feels like the type of thing that could be reported by commands like [connectionStatus](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/connectionStatus/) or [connPoolStats](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/connPoolStats/). So it may be worth opening a feature request for.

Some TLS information *is* captured in the log file by default when client connections are established. You mentioned that you don't have access to the configuration files so I'm assuming that you don't have direct access to the logs either. However, there is a [getLog command](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/getLog/) that can be used from a MongoDB shell session to pull some of this information. Starting an instance in `preferTLS` mode, connecting via the shell (without TLS), and issuing that command yielded the following:

```
test> db.adminCommand({getLog:"global"})
{
  totalLinesWritten: 47,
  log: [
    ...
    '{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-24T10:42:40.262-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:48134","uuid":"a5816945-d689-42e8-989b-f19e62bf65e7","connectionId":4,"connectionCount":4}}\n',
    `{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-24T10:42:40.264-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23838,   "ctx":"conn4","msg":"SSL mode is set to 'preferred' and connection to remote is not using SSL.","attr":{"connectionId":4,"remote":"127.0.0.1:48134"}}\n`, 
    ...
  ],
  ok: 1
}
```

Reformatting the second log line shown:

```
{
  t: { '$date': '2022-10-24T10:42:40.264-05:00' },
  s: 'I',
  c: 'NETWORK',
  id: 23838,
  ctx: 'conn4',
  msg: "SSL mode is set to 'preferred' and connection to remote is not using SSL.",
  attr: { connectionId: 4, remote: '127.0.0.1:48134' }
}
```

That above reports that `conn4` is `not using SSL`.

Comment: Ah this from the logs looks interesting thanks alot , I will accept this answer ...